# How to change bibliography style in a overleaf template?

Tags: biblatex

I would like to use the following template

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/cachet-technical-report-template/yrhcctsfmywd

But I would like to change the bibliography style. For instance in Chapter 3 at page 7 the authors do `\cite{adams1980hitchhiker}` and it displays **adams1980hitchhiker**.

How can I change the type of display from this style to numbers?

Comment: Did you  run `biber` or `bibtex`? It displays the citation key.

Comment: I am just compiling it on overleaf online

Comment: I don't use overleaf, but is launching Biber/bibtex automatic or does it have to be run by hand? The normal cycle is `latex->bib engine->latex (twice)`.

Comment: The problem comes from the template, the reference `adams1980hitchhiker` is not defined in their `.bib` file. Define it and everything works well.

Comment: All other citations except `adams1980hitchhiker` work fine. And indeed if you check out `bibliography/Bibliography.bib` you'll find that there is no entry `adams1980hitchhiker` there. Simply remove the reference and concentrate on the other entries that do work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are somehow forced to use this template I suggest you look for something that is smaller and easier to handle. The code of the template consists of hundreds of lines of code spread across a dozen or so files.

As [KersouMan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/184389/kersouman) notes [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550078/how-to-change-bibliography-style-in-a-overleaf-template#comment1389373_550078), the entry `adams1980hitchhiker` is a bit of a red herring. For some reason that entry is not present in the provided `.bib` file `bibliography/Bibliography.bib` in the template. Indeed there is a warning about this (slightly reformatted)

```
Package biblatex Warning: The following entry could not be found in the database:
                          adams1980hitchhiker
                          Please verify the spelling and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

`biblatex` shows the entry key of missing entries in bold when they are cited. That is what's happening here.

All other entries are cited in `alphabetic` style, so for example `brooke1996sus` in Appendix 1 (p. 19, `appendices/Appendix.tex`) is shown as

> [Bro+96]

If you want this template to produce numeric citations, go to the file `preamble/general.sty` and modify the `biblatex` call from

```
% Bibliography (references)
\usepackage[backend=biber,
            style=alphabetic,
            %backref=true,
            abbreviate=false,
            dateabbrev=false,
            alldates=long]{biblatex}
```

to

```
% Bibliography (references)
\usepackage[backend=biber,
            style=numeric,
            %backref=true,
            abbreviate=false,
            dateabbrev=false,
            alldates=long]{biblatex}
```

---

But if at all possible, do yourself a favour and start from something less complex.

```
\documentclass[british]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem}
Lorem ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson} dolor \autocite{worman}.

\chapter{Dolor}
Dolor \autocite{geer} sit \autocite{nussbaum} amet.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```